# Function that would be called when a variable changes

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a function that I want it to be called automatically when a specific variable changes.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the setter of a property to do this:

```
Private _YourObject As Object
Public Property YourObject() As Object
    Get
        Return _YourObject 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        _YourObject = value
        ExecuteYourFunction()
    End Set
End Property
```

This way, any time your property is set, the function `ExecuteYourFunction` is called.

Keep in mind, this isn't necessarily semantically or functionally identical to "when a specific variable *changes*" - `ExecuteYourFunction` is called when your "specific variable" is *set*, not when it is changed to a different value than it previously held. If you needed to execute a function if and only if the value assigned to your property was different than the value it previously held, you'd want to add a conditional to check (pre-assignment) whether `value` was inequal to `yourObject` and only call `ExecuteYourFunction` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this a a comment to furkle's answer, but you have to have 50 reputation to comment and I only have 46.

Since VB is case insensitive, you need to name the backing variable something besides yourObject.  One popular way would be to call it _YourObject, which is what the compiler would call it if it you just did

```
   Public Property YourObject As Object
```

without specifying the Get/Set methods.